# How do I turn off the "fading to black" in my Beamer titlebar?

Tags: beamer

I would like the titlebar in my Beamer presentations to be a solid color (like the bars at the bottom of the slides). Below I have defined a color "orange" in my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.4,0}
\usecolortheme[named=orange]{structure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.2in,text margin right=0.2in} 
\author[Author]{}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}[t]{Title Bar}
Here is some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

How do I get the title bar to be a solid orange instead of fading into black from left to right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=frametitle.bg}`  as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.4,0}
\usecolortheme[named=orange]{structure}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.2in,text margin right=0.2in} 

\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=frametitle.bg}

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}[t]{Title Bar}
Here is some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```